# How do I get the current project name in command line using node?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

If I am inside a project, I'd like to be able to run a command that outputs the name of that project dynamically. Is there a native yarn command?

Note that macs don't have `jq` (which would make it easy...just read package.json`

Example

```
my-project
  - package.json <- read package name
  - src
     - some_mod <- run command here in command line (ex: `yarn getCurrentPackage`)
```

Comment: Vote on [this proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354583/disentangle-the-yarn) to ease the tag confusion around [yarn] and [yarnpkg].

Answer (score 3):

Here you go!

```
PACKAGE_NAME=$(cut -d "=" -f 2 <<< $(npm run env | grep "npm_package_name"))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, MIke! Slightly easier to read, but exact same solution is: PACKAGE_NAME=$( npm run env | grep npm_package_name | cut -d= -f2 )